# dynamically giving input to date format for parsing D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am parsing date with the function

```
parseDate = d3.time.format("%m-%Y").parse;
```

its working nice if the date format i am giving is month and year.. but i want to make the format "%m-%Y" on run time dynamically.because some time i need format as %d-%m-%Y .

so how to make this parseDate function to take argument date as well as the format?I have the format in the json data.according to that data i will select the parsing function of give argument to parseDate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
function parseDate(format, date) {
  return d3.time.format(format).parse(date);
}
```